# Editing a web part page - Get ServiceActivationException error message

Tags: 2010, web-part, service

Create a web part page by
Site Actions > More Options > Filter by Page > Click Web part page > then Create

Enter a name add to Pages Document Library click Ok,
Within the page click Add Web Part
Add any ootb web part and click stop editing.

Go back to the page and click Edit Page - get JavaScript popup with this message

> Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is '500'.
>   The status text of response is
>   'System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException'.

Looking in the event viewer we have additional message

> WebHost failed to process a request.  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/31364015 
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/_vti_bin/client.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during
>   compilation.  The exception message is: A relative URI cannot be
>   created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute
>   URI.http://servername.company.com/_vti_bin/client.svc. --->
>   System.UriFormatException: A relative URI cannot be created because
>   the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute
>   URI.http://servername.company.com/_vti_bin/client.svc    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ApplyHostConfigurationBehavior.ThrowIfAbsolute(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ApplyHostConfigurationBehavior.FailActivationIfEndpointsHaveAbsoluteAddress(ServiceHostBase
>   service)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.ValidateDescription(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath)  Process Name: w3wp  Process ID: 8700

If we put http://servername.company.com/_vti_bin/Client.svc direct into the browser we get the same error message ie

> A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter
>   represents an absolute
>   URI.http://servername.company.com/_vti_bin/Client.svc

I thought this might be due to alternate access mappings, or bindings or host file but after trying some of the other services CellStorage did work, ie
http://servername.company.com/_vti_bin/CellStorage.svc does work.

Can anyone provide input on how to successfully edit the web part page?
If any further information would be useful please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I also found the link provided by @IAfanasonv yesterday; Extended Protection was already turned off.

Found some other information regarding setting the following aspNetCompatibilityEnabled property to true, this also had already been done.

this doesnt work.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

The fix was to remove the multipleSiteBindingsEnabled setting.
ie the following works.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

The multipleSiteBindingsEnabled was added so [CMIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934619%28v=office.14%29.aspx) works

So CMIS is currently broken and I need to find a way for both to co-exist.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9cdf5def-5019-4e82-83a2-e62cf0785bf6/sharepoint-2010-serviceactivationexception-wepapps-dont-work-cannot-connect-with-sharepoint

> Found the solution! :-) (except Word WebApp)
>
> After inspecting the windows event log I found the following exception
>
> Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The Service
> "/_vti_bin/client.svc" could not be activated because of an exception
> during compilation. The message of the exception is: The extended
> protection settings configured on IIS do not match the settings
> configured on the transport.  See inner exception for details.. --->
> System.NotSupportedException: The extended protection settings
> configured on IIS do not match the settings configured on the
> transport.  See inner exception for details. --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: The
> ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement values do not match.  One
> policy has a value of WhenSupported, while the other has a value of
> Never.  These values must match exactly.
>
> When searching for extendet protection I found this site:
> http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/extendedProtection
>
> I looked at IIS and found that the settings of the extendet protection
> were set to "Accept". After changing them to "Off" the web services
> are working fine, I can connect via SharePoint Designer and i got no
> more error when using the site search.
>
> But now the Word WebApp still don't work. Excel WebApp works fine, I
> can open a file and edit it directly in the document library :-) But
> when I want to open a word file the page loads, I see the word ribbons
> on the top and then I got an unknown error and it said that I should
> try to open the file in normal word.